# conflicting dependencies - android studio

Tags: java, android, junit, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to add a dependency `giphy4j` in my project and this dependency is using `junit 4.8.1` but my project is using the latest `junit 4.12`.

*build.gradle(module:app):*

```
androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'at.mukprojects:giphy4j:1.0.1'
```

This configuration is giving me error on gradle sync.
When I change `androidTestCompile` to `compile` and vice versa, It works. I am not getting this point. I dig into dependency stuff `compile`, `apk`, `TestCompile` etc. but couldn't get the proper idea.( As I am a Freshman). And, this conflicting error is also not comprehensible.

**point 1**: Is compiling the junit(to release with apk) wrong? `junit 4.12` is set by default when I create a new project.

**point 2**: I don't want to configure my third-party-dependency with `androidTestCompile` becuase It does not show up in `release configuration` when I run `./gradlew app:androiddependencies`.

[./gradlew app:androiddependencies output](https://pastebin.com/zpKmmRAZ)

**Error**: Error:Conflict with dependency 'junit:junit' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (4.8.1) and test app (4.12) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.

Comment: Why don't you exclude junit from the other dependency?

Comment: So the gradle is  including junit two times? 
I assumed that the library depends upon `junit 4.8.1`. But my project using `4.12` version hence they are conflicting.

Comment: That's what the error says, yes. However, it's not clear why you get that error unless you are actually compiling the test dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Exclude junit from library.

```
compile ("at.mukprojects:giphy4j:1.0.1") {
    exclude group: 'junit', module: 'junit'
}
```

Comment: Did you tried? It will not force giphy4j to use ` junit 4.12`. It just exclude that library to be added in your app module gradle.

Comment: Doing so trigger an error. `Error:(3, 17) error: package org.junit does not exist` for `ExampleUnitTest.java`